# error in building speech tools for festival2.1 under gcc in mac osx 10.8.5

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, text-to-speech

The errors below occured while compiling/building speech tool 2.1 for festival 2.1 under gcc in mac osx 10.8.5

```
In file included from siod.cc:31:
In file included from ../include/EST_THash.h:46:
../include/EST_TIterator.h:212:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'begin'
    { begin(over); }
      ^
      this->

../include/EST_TIterator.h:292:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'begin'
    { begin(over); }
      ^
      this->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to update GCC and everything was okay.
the gcc in apple was 4.2 or something before that and I installed macports and installed gcc 4.9 gcc version 4.9.0 20131215 (experimental) (MacPorts gcc49 4.9-20131215_0)

Comment: update GCC to which version? If you're going to answer your own question, let's see some detail :)

Comment: the gcc in apple was 4.2 or something before that and I installed macports and installed gcc 4.9
gcc version 4.9.0 20131215 (experimental) (MacPorts gcc49 4.9-20131215_0)